# Prove that a Cauchy sequence is periodic if and only if it is constant?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

I'm wondering in how to start this problem. Thank you

Comment: Prove it by contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a_n$ is periodic of period $M$ and *not* constant, then there exists $m\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\delta >0$ such that $|a_{(nM)+m}-a_{(nM)}|>\delta$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Nice! Do you have an idea of how to prove the converse?

Comment: @paulmuaddib: The converse is that a constant sequence is periodic; that’s trivial.